# How to check if all rows of dataGridView can be inserted in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a dataGridView table and I want to insert all the rows to the database via TableAdapter. The problem is that if there is incorrect foreign key in some row then it triggers SQL exception but the previous rows are already inserted.

So, I want to check if all the rows can be inserted and after that insert them all.

```
        for(int i = 0; !dataGridView1.Rows[i].IsNewRow; i++)
        {
           productInInvoiceTableAdapter.Insert(
               dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), 
               Convert.ToInt32(invoiceTableAdapter.MaxId().Value),
               Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value));
        }
```

Comment: You could wrap that in a transaction and rollback if everything did not succeed. But that is not a great way to manage data, you can use databinding to make one call instead of looping.

Comment: My first question I'd be asking myself, is how can I eliminate the problem in my source data.  You mentioned that  'some' rows have this problem, others don't.  Ideally I'd try and get that fixed first.  Based on your description you could do a lookup on each row before hand and based on the results of that operation decide if to do the inserts or not.

Comment: Doing inserts row by agonizing row is not an ideal way to handle this. A table valued parameter would be a better approach. But you have a number of validation issues you need to deal with first.